# How to Search in Sql Server Compact Database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I created application that relay on `SqlServerCompact` Database,in which i want to filter data through `DataGridView`,how to achieve this task? any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

My Code

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.IO;

namespace DemoLocalDataBase
{
    public partial class frmView : Form
    {
        public static SqlCeDataAdapter sda = null;

        #region Constructor
        public frmView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CurdOperation();
            this.BindGrid();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Create connection to the local database
        /// <summary>
        /// Here i have to use SqlCeConnection Class.
        /// </summary>
        private static void CurdOperation()
        {
            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source="
                + System.IO.Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "MyDB.sdf"));
            sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
            SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from MyDemoTable";
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

            SqlCeCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(sda);
            sda.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
            sda.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
            sda.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();
        }
        #endregion
        #region PageSepcific Method

        /// <summary>
        /// this is common method created for Add,Update,Delete case.
        /// In this method normaly fill dataset with olddata.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="oldData"></param>
        /// <param name="dr"></param>
        private static void FillDataInDataset(out DataSet oldData, out DataRow dr)
        {
            oldData = new DataSet();
            dr = null;
            sda.Fill(oldData);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// In this method get all data from table and 
        /// bind grid with data.
        /// </summary>
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(_ds);
            if (_ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                dgvOldData2.DataSource = _ds.Tables[0];
            }
        #endregion
        }
```

Please give me proper answer cause i am the beginner in programming duds.